# haproxy rewrite rule ony for a certain backend

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

Is it possible to have a rewrite rule to modify the URI for a certian backend? 
/old/context/path to /new/context/path

My use case is, I have % weighted traffic distribution between legacy & new stack. For Old stack "Old Context Path" works fine but for new stack, we need to have rewrite rule in haproxy.

can you please suggest, if possible snippet would help too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic because it should be on Server Fault.

Comment: This is a tricky proposition, because HAProxy generally works under an assumption that all servers in a given backend are interchangeable.  Please provide your HAProxy version from `haproxy -v` and we can look for a workaround.

Comment: Haproxy version - haproxy-1.6.4